# Compute this integral using parameterization

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

> Find $$\int_C\left(\frac{1}{x+y}\textbf{i}+\frac{1}{x+y}\textbf{j}\right)\cdot \text{d}r$$where $C$ is the segment of the unit circle going counterclockwise from $(1,0)$ to $(0,1)$.

I did this problem by the fundamental theorem of line integrals. But the real question was to make this question by **direct parameterization**. I tried applying the common parameters but couldn't proceed. Actually, I have a little idea about this method. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Parametrize and substitute. What is the problem? Why couldn't you proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A parametrization of $C$ is given by
$$
r(t)=(\cos t,\sin t) \quad 0 \le t \le \frac{\pi}{2},
$$
and
$$
r'(t)=-\sin t \mathbf{i}+\cos t\mathbf{j},
$$
so we have

\begin{eqnarray}
\int_C\left(\frac{1}{x+y}\mathbf{i}+\frac{1}{x+y}\mathbf{j}\right)\cdot dr 
&=& \int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{\cos t+\sin t}(\mathbf{i}+\mathbf{j})\cdot(-\sin t \mathbf{i}+\cos t\mathbf{j}) dt\cr
&=& \int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{-\sin t+\cos t}{\cos t+\sin t}dt \cr
&=&\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{(\cos t+\sin t)'}{\cos t+\sin t}dt\cr
&=& \ln(\cos t+\sin t)\Big|_0^{\pi/2} \cr
&=&\ln(1)-\ln(1)\cr
&=&0.
\end{eqnarray}